# Backbone dropdown change doesn't update model in a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and I have this problem while learning, which I was trying to solve it for some time and it get's annoying. I'm rendering one dropdown for each of the attributes in the model. When I change the selected value, I would like to update the model. When I try to catch the change event in OrderView, it does not work. If I do that in the OrderingView, it works, but then I need to search for the current model.

What am I doing wrong here?

The situation: I have this model:

```
var Order = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults:{
                column: '',
                order: ''
            }

       });
```

and corresponding collection having Order as model. The Views:

```
var orderView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: new Order(),
            initialize: function(){
                this.template = _.template(order_template);

            },
            render: function(){
                var temp = this.template({model:this.model.toJSON(),order_columns:this.order_columns});
                this.$el.html(temp);
                return this;
            },
            events: {
                'change .order_columns': 'change_column'
            },
            change_column: function(){
                  console.log('column changed..');
            }
        });

var orderingView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: new OrderCollection(),
            initialize: function(){

                var that = this;
                _(this.options.orderings).each(function(or){
                   that.model.add(new Order({column: or.column, order: or.order}));
                });

                this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
                this.model.on('change', this.changed_item,this);

            },
            render: function(){

                var that = this;
                that.$el.html('');

                var temp_order = '';

                _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(ordering, i){
                    var obj = new orderView({model: ordering, order_columns: that.options.order_columns}).render().$el.html();
                    temp_order += obj;     
                });

                var temp = _.template(ordering_template,{element: temp_order});
                that.$el.html(temp);

                $(document).ready(function(){

                    $('.add-ordering').click(function(){

                         var new_order = new Order({column: 'none', order: 'ASCENDING'});
                         that.model.add(new_order);

                    });
                });

                return this;
            },

        });
```

and the call is from different file using requirejs:

```
that.orderView = new orderingView({el:table, 
                    orderings: that.data.models.layers[0].orderings, 
                    order_columns:that.data.models.layers[0].columns});
```

Also I load the html templates at the beginning using requirejs and known as order_template and ordering_template

templates:

```html
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls" style="margin-left:30px;">
        <select class="order_columns" name="columns" style="float:left;">
                            <option value='none' <%=model.column==='none'? 'selected': ''%>>None</option>   
                             <% _(order_columns).each(function(col){ %>   
                             <option value="<%=col.alias%>" <%=model.column===col.alias? 'selected': ''%>><%= col.name %></option>
                             <% }); %>   
        </select>
        <select class="ordering" name="ordering" style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
                                <option value='ASCENDING' <%=model.order === 'ASCENDING'? 'selected':''%> >ASC</option>
                                <option value='DESCENDING' <%=model.order === 'DESCENDING'? 'selected':''%>>DESC</option>
        </select>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close ui-order-close <%=model.column%>" style="margin-left:10px;"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and ordering_template

```html
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal span12">
    <fieldset>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span9 ordering_div" style="width:520px;">
                     <%=element%>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Most likely the problem is that your view(s) has no root DOM element ([`this.el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)) bound with. That's because you neither specify any of DOM properties (`tagName`, `className`, `id`) nor specify `el` property explicitly.

Comment: I tried adding element tags, while on the main view there is an element tag parsed while creation. Can you please specify what exactly should I do..I'm confused that the rendering of each individual model works, but the change event does not fire.

Comment: What do the templates look like? How do you instantiate the views and how do you get them on the page? Any chance of seeing a minimal functional demo on jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: Thanks for you post. I add the two different templates in the initial post. Do you have any suggestion? The initial view is called from a different file like stated above. When I debug, the rendering works and I see the dropdowns, but if I want to catch the change event in the model, nothing works.